# HTML CSS How to remove scroll bar and make the website full screen?

Tags: html, css, web, scrollbar, fullscreen

This is a code of a website with header and three columns. The main idea is to create 100% width and height website for all screen resolutions. The website should be full screen and only the content (second column) with scroll bar. The problem is that the website is not 100% and it still has scroll bar...
I added a screen shot here to make sense and also the code(marked my problem in red). If anyone knows how to get rid of the scroll bar and make it 100% full screen, I would be very grateful.

[image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>UBM</title>
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
header
</div>
<div id="lcr">
<div id="lsidebar">
<div id="row_refine_your_search">
Refine your search
</div>
<div id="year">
Year:
<select data-placeholder="Choose your year..." class="labas" style="width:90%;" tabindex="-1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="First Year">First Year</option>
            <option value="Second Year">Second Year</option>
            <option value="Third Year">Third Year</option>
          </select>
</div>
<div id="course">
Course:
<select data-placeholder="Choose your course..." class="labas" style="width:90%;" tabindex="-1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Applied Computing">Applied Computing</option>
            <option value="Computer Games Design">Computer Games Design </option>
            <option value="Computer Games Programming">Computer Games Programming</option>
            <option value="Computer Games Technology">Computer Games Technology</option>
            <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
            <option value="Computing in Business">Computing in Business</option>
            <option value="Computing Science">Computing Science</option>
            <option value="ICT">ICT</option>
            <option value="Software Engineering">Software Engineering</option>
          </select>
</div>
<div id="year">
Module:
<select data-placeholder="Choose your module..." class="labas" style="width:90%;" tabindex="-1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Computing Science and Mathematics">Computing Science and Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Hardware and Networks">Hardware and Networks</option>
            <option value="Studio 1">Studio 1</option>
            <option value="Project 1">Project 1</option>
            <option value="Software Design and Development">Software Design and Development</option>
            <option value="Algorithms Processes and Data">Algorithms Processes and Data</option>
          </select>
</div>
<div id="row_recent_research">
Recent research
</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
Jos teigimu, į kiekvieną buvusio vyro skundą, nors jie ir neturi pagrindo, operatyviai reaguojančios tarnybos apsunkina Jolantos ir jos nepilnamečių dukrų gyvenimą. Mergaitės net atsisako kalbėtis su socialinėmis darbuotojomis, yra dirglios ir pavargusios dėl nuolatinio vaikų teisių tarnybų kišimosi į šeimos gyvenimą. Jolanta pabrėžia – ji nėra nei asociali, nei narkomanė, nei alkoholikė, tačiau moteris yra nuolat priversta turėti reikalų su vaiko teisių tarnybomis: „Buvęs vyras keršija man, kad su juo išsiskyriau, ir padedamas įvairių tarnybų nuolat persekioja mane ir vaikus bei drumsčia mūsų šeimos gyvenimą“, – pasakojo Jolanta. Jolanta savo tikrojo vardo nenorėjo skelbti dėl to, kad jos dukros yra paauglės ir susidariusią situaciją su tėvu stipriai išgyvena. Papasakoti šios moters istoriją painu. Pati Jolanta sako – jos atvejis svarbus ne tuo, kad jos santykiai su vyru susiklostė nesėkmingai. Svarbiausia, jos nuomone – institucijų, kurios turėtų ginti vaikus ir jų interesus, elgesys. Pavyzdžiui, kodėl dukros apklausoje dalyvavusios Vilniaus savivaldybės vaiko teisių apsaugos skyriaus specialistės skaudino ir žemino dvylikametę Jolantos dukrą? Kodėl ji ir jos dukros yra stebimos psichologų, kurie turi duoti ataskaitą Vaiko teisių kontrolieriaus tarnybai? Kodėl nuolat pabrėžiama, kad Jolanta trukdo vaikams atkurti ryšį su tėvu, bei siūloma organizuoti bendrus susitikimus psichologo kabinete, kai patys vaikai to nenori, o juolab bijo tėvo? Dar daugiau – kodėl Jolanta gavo oficialų įspėjimą iš Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolierės, jeigu ji nepadarė nieko blogo? Jolantos nuomone, tokių tėvų, kurie vieniši augina vaikus, o vaikus ginti turinčios institucijos tik apsunkina jų gyvenimą – yra ne viena. Nori gyventi ramiai „Gerai besielgiantys ir besimokantys vaikai dėl buvusio mano vyro nuolat tampomi vaikų teisių tarnybų. Sveikiems vaikams dėl vyro užgaidų buvo skirta teismo psichologinė ekspertizė. Rezultatai buvusiam vyrui nepatiko, jis pareiškė, kad teismo ekspertė netinkamai atliko savo darbą. Aš ir mano dukros norime ramiai gyventi, o ne būti nuolat tampomos po įvairias tarnybas, visokio plauko socialinius darbuotojus ir psichologus“, – sakė Jolanta. Jos teigimu, paauglės mergaitės tik nori, kad tėvas paliktų jas ramybėje, ir išgyvena, kad yra nuolat jo persekiojamos ir tampomos po visokias institucijas, tenkinant tėvo užgaidas ir interesus. „Vyras ir toliau mane ir vaikus persekioja ir terorizuoja, tik padedamas vaikų teisių tarnybų, o tos tarnybos nesirūpina, kaip užtikrinti vaikų ramybę, jos tik žiūri, kaip apginti netinkamai besielgiantį tėvą“, – tikino Jolanta. Gavo įspėjimą Po vieno įprasto buvusio Jolantos vyro skundo Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolieriaus tarnyba atliko tyrimą. Buvo nuspręsta įspėti moterį už trukdymą tėvui susitikti ir bendrauti su dukromis pagal teismo patvirtintą bendravimo su dukromis tvarką. Buvo paminėta ir tai, kad Jolanta vengia padėti atkurti dukrų ryšį su tėvu, tam pasitelkiant psichologo konsultacijas. Jos teigimu, į kiekvieną buvusio vyro skundą, nors jie ir neturi pagrindo, operatyviai reaguojančios tarnybos apsunkina Jolantos ir jos nepilnamečių dukrų gyvenimą. Mergaitės net atsisako kalbėtis su socialinėmis darbuotojomis, yra dirglios ir pavargusios dėl nuolatinio vaikų teisių tarnybų kišimosi į šeimos gyvenimą. Jolanta pabrėžia – ji nėra nei asociali, nei narkomanė, nei alkoholikė, tačiau moteris yra nuolat priversta turėti reikalų su vaiko teisių tarnybomis: „Buvęs vyras keršija man, kad su juo išsiskyriau, ir padedamas įvairių tarnybų nuolat persekioja mane ir vaikus bei drumsčia mūsų šeimos gyvenimą“, – pasakojo Jolanta. Jolanta savo tikrojo vardo nenorėjo skelbti dėl to, kad jos dukros yra paauglės ir susidariusią situaciją su tėvu stipriai išgyvena. Papasakoti šios moters istoriją painu. Pati Jolanta sako – jos atvejis svarbus ne tuo, kad jos santykiai su vyru susiklostė nesėkmingai. Svarbiausia, jos nuomone – institucijų, kurios turėtų ginti vaikus ir jų interesus, elgesys. Pavyzdžiui, kodėl dukros apklausoje dalyvavusios Vilniaus savivaldybės vaiko teisių apsaugos skyriaus specialistės skaudino ir žemino dvylikametę Jolantos dukrą? Kodėl ji ir jos dukros yra stebimos psichologų, kurie turi duoti ataskaitą Vaiko teisių kontrolieriaus tarnybai? Kodėl nuolat pabrėžiama, kad Jolanta trukdo vaikams atkurti ryšį su tėvu, bei siūloma organizuoti bendrus susitikimus psichologo kabinete, kai patys vaikai to nenori, o juolab bijo tėvo? Dar daugiau – kodėl Jolanta gavo oficialų įspėjimą iš Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolierės, jeigu ji nepadarė nieko blogo? Jolantos nuomone, tokių tėvų, kurie vieniši augina vaikus, o vaikus ginti turinčios institucijos tik apsunkina jų gyvenimą – yra ne viena. Nori gyventi ramiai „Gerai besielgiantys ir besimokantys vaikai dėl buvusio mano vyro nuolat tampomi vaikų teisių tarnybų. Sveikiems vaikams dėl vyro užgaidų buvo skirta teismo psichologinė ekspertizė. Rezultatai buvusiam vyrui nepatiko, jis pareiškė, kad teismo ekspertė netinkamai atliko savo darbą. Aš ir mano dukros norime ramiai gyventi, o ne būti nuolat tampomos po įvairias tarnybas, visokio plauko socialinius darbuotojus ir psichologus“, – sakė Jolanta. Jos teigimu, paauglės mergaitės tik nori, kad tėvas paliktų jas ramybėje, ir išgyvena, kad yra nuolat jo persekiojamos ir tampomos po visokias institucijas, tenkinant tėvo užgaidas ir interesus. „Vyras ir toliau mane ir vaikus persekioja ir terorizuoja, tik padedamas vaikų teisių tarnybų, o tos tarnybos nesirūpina, kaip užtikrinti vaikų ramybę, jos tik žiūri, kaip apginti netinkamai besielgiantį tėvą“, – tikino Jolanta. Gavo įspėjimą Po vieno įprasto buvusio Jolantos vyro skundo Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolieriaus tarnyba atliko tyrimą. Buvo nuspręsta įspėti moterį už trukdymą tėvui susitikti ir bendrauti su dukromis pagal teismo patvirtintą bendravimo su dukromis tvarką. Buvo paminėta ir tai, kad Jolanta vengia padėti atkurti dukrų ryšį su tėvu, tam pasitelkiant psichologo konsultacijas. Jos teigimu, į kiekvieną buvusio vyro skundą, nors jie ir neturi pagrindo, operatyviai reaguojančios tarnybos apsunkina Jolantos ir jos nepilnamečių dukrų gyvenimą. Mergaitės net atsisako kalbėtis su socialinėmis darbuotojomis, yra dirglios ir pavargusios dėl nuolatinio vaikų teisių tarnybų kišimosi į šeimos gyvenimą. Jolanta pabrėžia – ji nėra nei asociali, nei narkomanė, nei alkoholikė, tačiau moteris yra nuolat priversta turėti reikalų su vaiko teisių tarnybomis: „Buvęs vyras keršija man, kad su juo išsiskyriau, ir padedamas įvairių tarnybų nuolat persekioja mane ir vaikus bei drumsčia mūsų šeimos gyvenimą“, – pasakojo Jolanta. Jolanta savo tikrojo vardo nenorėjo skelbti dėl to, kad jos dukros yra paauglės ir susidariusią situaciją su tėvu stipriai išgyvena. Papasakoti šios moters istoriją painu. Pati Jolanta sako – jos atvejis svarbus ne tuo, kad jos santykiai su vyru susiklostė nesėkmingai. Svarbiausia, jos nuomone – institucijų, kurios turėtų ginti vaikus ir jų interesus, elgesys. Pavyzdžiui, kodėl dukros apklausoje dalyvavusios Vilniaus savivaldybės vaiko teisių apsaugos skyriaus specialistės skaudino ir žemino dvylikametę Jolantos dukrą? Kodėl ji ir jos dukros yra stebimos psichologų, kurie turi duoti ataskaitą Vaiko teisių kontrolieriaus tarnybai? Kodėl nuolat pabrėžiama, kad Jolanta trukdo vaikams atkurti ryšį su tėvu, bei siūloma organizuoti bendrus susitikimus psichologo kabinete, kai patys vaikai to nenori, o juolab bijo tėvo? Dar daugiau – kodėl Jolanta gavo oficialų įspėjimą iš Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolierės, jeigu ji nepadarė nieko blogo? Jolantos nuomone, tokių tėvų, kurie vieniši augina vaikus, o vaikus ginti turinčios institucijos tik apsunkina jų gyvenimą – yra ne viena. Nori gyventi ramiai „Gerai besielgiantys ir besimokantys vaikai dėl buvusio mano vyro nuolat tampomi vaikų teisių tarnybų. Sveikiems vaikams dėl vyro užgaidų buvo skirta teismo psichologinė ekspertizė. Rezultatai buvusiam vyrui nepatiko, jis pareiškė, kad teismo ekspertė netinkamai atliko savo darbą. Aš ir mano dukros norime ramiai gyventi, o ne būti nuolat tampomos po įvairias tarnybas, visokio plauko socialinius darbuotojus ir psichologus“, – sakė Jolanta. Jos teigimu, paauglės mergaitės tik nori, kad tėvas paliktų jas ramybėje, ir išgyvena, kad yra nuolat jo persekiojamos ir tampomos po visokias institucijas, tenkinant tėvo užgaidas ir interesus. „Vyras ir toliau mane ir vaikus persekioja ir terorizuoja, tik padedamas vaikų teisių tarnybų, o tos tarnybos nesirūpina, kaip užtikrinti vaikų ramybę, jos tik žiūri, kaip apginti netinkamai besielgiantį tėvą“, – tikino Jolanta. Gavo įspėjimą Po vieno įprasto buvusio Jolantos vyro skundo Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolieriaus tarnyba atliko tyrimą. Buvo nuspręsta įspėti moterį už trukdymą tėvui susitikti ir bendrauti su dukromis pagal teismo patvirtintą bendravimo su dukromis tvarką. Buvo paminėta ir tai, kad Jolanta vengia padėti atkurti dukrų ryšį su tėvu, tam pasitelkiant psichologo konsultacijas. Jos teigimu, į kiekvieną buvusio vyro skundą, nors jie ir neturi pagrindo, operatyviai reaguojančios tarnybos apsunkina Jolantos ir jos nepilnamečių dukrų gyvenimą. Mergaitės net atsisako kalbėtis su socialinėmis darbuotojomis, yra dirglios ir pavargusios dėl nuolatinio vaikų teisių tarnybų kišimosi į šeimos gyvenimą. Jolanta pabrėžia – ji nėra nei asociali, nei narkomanė, nei alkoholikė, tačiau moteris yra nuolat priversta turėti reikalų su vaiko teisių tarnybomis: „Buvęs vyras keršija man, kad su juo išsiskyriau, ir padedamas įvairių tarnybų nuolat persekioja mane ir vaikus bei drumsčia mūsų šeimos gyvenimą“, – pasakojo Jolanta. Jolanta savo tikrojo vardo nenorėjo skelbti dėl to, kad jos dukros yra paauglės ir susidariusią situaciją su tėvu stipriai išgyvena. Papasakoti šios moters istoriją painu. Pati Jolanta sako – jos atvejis svarbus ne tuo, kad jos santykiai su vyru susiklostė nesėkmingai. Svarbiausia, jos nuomone – institucijų, kurios turėtų ginti vaikus ir jų interesus, elgesys. Pavyzdžiui, kodėl dukros apklausoje dalyvavusios Vilniaus savivaldybės vaiko teisių apsaugos skyriaus specialistės skaudino ir žemino dvylikametę Jolantos dukrą? Kodėl ji ir jos dukros yra stebimos psichologų, kurie turi duoti ataskaitą Vaiko teisių kontrolieriaus tarnybai? Kodėl nuolat pabrėžiama, kad Jolanta trukdo vaikams atkurti ryšį su tėvu, bei siūloma organizuoti bendrus susitikimus psichologo kabinete, kai patys vaikai to nenori, o juolab bijo tėvo? Dar daugiau – kodėl Jolanta gavo oficialų įspėjimą iš Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolierės, jeigu ji nepadarė nieko blogo? Jolantos nuomone, tokių tėvų, kurie vieniši augina vaikus, o vaikus ginti turinčios institucijos tik apsunkina jų gyvenimą – yra ne viena. Nori gyventi ramiai „Gerai besielgiantys ir besimokantys vaikai dėl buvusio mano vyro nuolat tampomi vaikų teisių tarnybų. Sveikiems vaikams dėl vyro užgaidų buvo skirta teismo psichologinė ekspertizė. Rezultatai buvusiam vyrui nepatiko, jis pareiškė, kad teismo ekspertė netinkamai atliko savo darbą. Aš ir mano dukros norime ramiai gyventi, o ne būti nuolat tampomos po įvairias tarnybas, visokio plauko socialinius darbuotojus ir psichologus“, – sakė Jolanta. Jos teigimu, paauglės mergaitės tik nori, kad tėvas paliktų jas ramybėje, ir išgyvena, kad yra nuolat jo persekiojamos ir tampomos po visokias institucijas, tenkinant tėvo užgaidas ir interesus. „Vyras ir toliau mane ir vaikus persekioja ir terorizuoja, tik padedamas vaikų teisių tarnybų, o tos tarnybos nesirūpina, kaip užtikrinti vaikų ramybę, jos tik žiūri, kaip apginti netinkamai besielgiantį tėvą“, – tikino Jolanta. Gavo įspėjimą Po vieno įprasto buvusio Jolantos vyro skundo Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolieriaus tarnyba atliko tyrimą. Buvo nuspręsta įspėti moterį už trukdymą tėvui susitikti ir bendrauti su dukromis pagal teismo patvirtintą bendravimo su dukromis tvarką. Buvo paminėta ir tai, kad Jolanta vengia padėti atkurti dukrų ryšį su tėvu, tam pasitelkiant psichologo konsultacijas. Jos teigimu, į kiekvieną buvusio vyro skundą, nors jie ir neturi pagrindo, operatyviai reaguojančios tarnybos apsunkina Jolantos ir jos nepilnamečių dukrų gyvenimą. Mergaitės net atsisako kalbėtis su socialinėmis darbuotojomis, yra dirglios ir pavargusios dėl nuolatinio vaikų teisių tarnybų kišimosi į šeimos gyvenimą. Jolanta pabrėžia – ji nėra nei asociali, nei narkomanė, nei alkoholikė, tačiau moteris yra nuolat priversta turėti reikalų su vaiko teisių tarnybomis: „Buvęs vyras keršija man, kad su juo išsiskyriau, ir padedamas įvairių tarnybų nuolat persekioja mane ir vaikus bei drumsčia mūsų šeimos gyvenimą“, – pasakojo Jolanta. Jolanta savo tikrojo vardo nenorėjo skelbti dėl to, kad jos dukros yra paauglės ir susidariusią situaciją su tėvu stipriai išgyvena. Papasakoti šios moters istoriją painu. Pati Jolanta sako – jos atvejis svarbus ne tuo, kad jos santykiai su vyru susiklostė nesėkmingai. Svarbiausia, jos nuomone – institucijų, kurios turėtų ginti vaikus ir jų interesus, elgesys. Pavyzdžiui, kodėl dukros apklausoje dalyvavusios Vilniaus savivaldybės vaiko teisių apsaugos skyriaus specialistės skaudino ir žemino dvylikametę Jolantos dukrą? Kodėl ji ir jos dukros yra stebimos psichologų, kurie turi duoti ataskaitą Vaiko teisių kontrolieriaus tarnybai? Kodėl nuolat pabrėžiama, kad Jolanta trukdo vaikams atkurti ryšį su tėvu, bei siūloma organizuoti bendrus susitikimus psichologo kabinete, kai patys vaikai to nenori, o juolab bijo tėvo? Dar daugiau – kodėl Jolanta gavo oficialų įspėjimą iš Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolierės, jeigu ji nepadarė nieko blogo? Jolantos nuomone, tokių tėvų, kurie vieniši augina vaikus, o vaikus ginti turinčios institucijos tik apsunkina jų gyvenimą – yra ne viena. Nori gyventi ramiai „Gerai besielgiantys ir besimokantys vaikai dėl buvusio mano vyro nuolat tampomi vaikų teisių tarnybų. Sveikiems vaikams dėl vyro užgaidų buvo skirta teismo psichologinė ekspertizė. Rezultatai buvusiam vyrui nepatiko, jis pareiškė, kad teismo ekspertė netinkamai atliko savo darbą. Aš ir mano dukros norime ramiai gyventi, o ne būti nuolat tampomos po įvairias tarnybas, visokio plauko socialinius darbuotojus ir psichologus“, – sakė Jolanta. Jos teigimu, paauglės mergaitės tik nori, kad tėvas paliktų jas ramybėje, ir išgyvena, kad yra nuolat jo persekiojamos ir tampomos po visokias institucijas, tenkinant tėvo užgaidas ir interesus. „Vyras ir toliau mane ir vaikus persekioja ir terorizuoja, tik padedamas vaikų teisių tarnybų, o tos tarnybos nesirūpina, kaip užtikrinti vaikų ramybę, jos tik žiūri, kaip apginti netinkamai besielgiantį tėvą“, – tikino Jolanta. Gavo įspėjimą Po vieno įprasto buvusio Jolantos vyro skundo Vaiko teisių apsaugos kontrolieriaus tarnyba atliko tyrimą. Buvo nuspręsta įspėti moterį už trukdymą tėvui susitikti ir bendrauti su dukromis pagal teismo patvirtintą bendravimo su dukromis tvarką. Buvo paminėta ir tai, kad Jolanta vengia padėti atkurti dukrų ryšį su tėvu, tam pasitelkiant psichologo konsultacijas.
</div>
<div id="rsidebar">
<div id="row_also_recomended">
Also recomended
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
footer
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
body {
    margin: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
}



#main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#main #header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    background: #33B5E5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), #33B5E5;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.5))), #33B5E5;
}
#main #lcr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}

#main #lcr #lsidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

#main #lcr #lsidebar #row_refine_your_search {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 7%;
    padding-bottom: 7%;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), #ffffff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.4))), #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    border-bottom-width: 0.063em;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #195b73;
}

#main #lcr #lsidebar #year {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size: large;
    padding-top: 7%;
}

#main #lcr #lsidebar #course {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size: large;
    padding-top: 7%;
}

#main #lcr #lsidebar #row_recent_research {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    padding-top: 7%;
    padding-bottom: 7%;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), #ffffff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.4))), #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    border-bottom-width: 0.063em;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #195b73;
    border-top-width: 0.063em;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #195b73;
}
#main #lcr #content{
    width: 60.62%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.6%;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
}
#main #lcr #rsidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    height: 100%;
}
#main #lcr #rsidebar #row_also_recomended {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 7%;
    padding-bottom: 7%;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), #ffffff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.4))), #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    border-bottom-width: 0.063em;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #195b73;
}
```

Comment: side note: use `padding:0;margin:0;`

Comment: Fixed my problem by using other method, thank all :)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the width % slightly so that the scrollbars do not appear .

Answer (score 0):

please try this
   body{
      overflow-x:hidden;
     }